# PHP move_uploaded_file failing. Uploaded file tmp_name is blank?

Tags: php, upload

Ok so I have the following code that is supposed to move the uploaded file. I have already created this directory and ran a if file_exists on it to make sure that php could see it (it can). This code fails with the following error:

```
[13-Oct-2014 18:52:07 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  fopen(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\uploads\tr.apk): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\main.php on line 395
[13-Oct-2014 18:52:07 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\uploads\tr.apk in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\main.php on line 396
[13-Oct-2014 18:52:07 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\main.php on line 396
[13-Oct-2014 18:52:07 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\main.php on line 397
```

And there is no file in the directory. I really can't figure out why its failing, I've even changed the permissions so that anyone can write to it. Also if I echo for the tmp name it returns nothing.

**Code:**

```
$uploaddir = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\PHPTesting\\uploads\\";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$_FILES['Attachment']['name'];
echo $uploadfile;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Attachment']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
echo "File uploaded.";
else
echo "File failed.". $_FILES['Attachment']['name'];
```

**Output:**

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\uploads\tr.apk. File failed tr.apk

**HTML Form:**

```
<form action="main.php"  name="sendMessageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden"  value="sendMessage" name="action">
To:<input type="text" name="To"><br/>
Cc:<input type="text" name="Cc"><br/>
Bcc:<input type="text" name="Bcc"><br/>
Subject:<input type="text" name="Subject"></br>
Message:<input type="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" name="Message"><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
Attachment:<input type="file" name="Attachment"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

Comment: What is your $_FILES['Attachment']['error'] value?

Comment: Check if the directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPTesting\uploads\ exists on your Server and the Webserver has all rights to write in it.

Comment: I did not set that value elsewhere, I have verified that everyone including the IIS user can write to it and the error code is a 2.

Comment: 2 Meaning that the file wasn't uploaded. The error code should be `0` for a successful upload. Please post your Form HTML Code.

Comment: Provlem found! `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />` You are setting the file Max Size to 30M but you are trying to upload a bigger file.

Comment: That isn't possible considering tp.apk is 111KB

Comment: Weird! Try removing that field to check if it the issue cause. (But normally it is the cause).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62997/discussion-between-php-dev-and-kyle).